# Internactionalization of Enum labels

Tags: java, enums, internationalization

i'm trying to internationalize label coming from a Enum

```
public enum WeekDay {
      MONDAY("msg.week_monday", "mon"), 
      TUESDAY("msg.week_tuesday", "tue"), 
      WEDNESDAY("msg.week_wednesday", "wed"),
      THURSDAY("msg.week_thursday", "thu"), 
      FRIDAY("msg.week_friday", "fri"), 
      SATURDAY("msg.week_saturday", "sat"),
      SUNDAY("msg.week_sunday", "sun");

        private String label;
        private String value;

        private WeekDay(String label, String value) {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;

        }
    }
```

on my selectOneMenu i got the list of this labels:

```
    <f:selectItems value="#{myMB.weekDays}"
                                        var="dayWeek" itemValue="#{dayWeek}"
                                        itemLabel="#{dayWeek.label}" />
```

i have some translation on my message.properties but i can't show the translation with Enum labels. If i use simple `itemLabel="#{msg.week_monday}"`  works.